# For $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ unique $f(n)\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ is mapped with $f(1)=1$, $f(f(n))=n$ and $f(2n)=2f(n)+1$. Find $f(2020)$.

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations, integers

**Problem**
For every positive integer $n$, a unique positive integer $f(n)$ is assigned in the following manner: $f(1)=1$ and for every positive integer $n$, $f(f(n))=n$ and $f(2n)=2f(n)+1$. Find the value of $f(2020)$ with a proof.

---

**My Approach**
**Given** : $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2[f(1)]+1=3$.

> **Claim $1$**: if $f(a)=b$, then $f(b)=a$ for all positive integers $a$ and $b$.
> **Proof**: $f(a)=b$, given $f(f(n))=n$, then $f[f(a)]=a$, therefore $f(b)=a$.

We know that $f(2)=3$, therefore $f(4)=7, f(8)=15, f(16)=31, f(32)=63$.

From **Claim $1$**

- $f(63)=32$. Then, $f(126)=65, f(252)=131$.
- $f(131)=252$, therefore $f(262)=505$.
- $f(505)=262$, therefore $f(1010)=525$, thus $f(2020)=1051$.

I want to know whether my proof given below is correct and whether there's a better proof than mine.

Comment: Questions on this website tend to not do well if not typed with MathJax. Would you mind transcribing the images?

Comment: @dxiv It's necessary to point out that the topic starter presumably wants to get $f(2020)$ without finding the $f$ itself (to make the proof simpler).

Comment: @Rusurano Fair point, changing "duplicate" to "related": [Find $f(n)$ where $f(2n)= 2f(n)+ 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071706/find-fn-where-f2n-2fn-1).

Comment: Images transcribed for the ease of access to the question to the potential answerers.

Comment: Also, good to know that it is https://oeis.org/A054429

Comment: @Rusurano Thanks for editing